# Return a value from an action (NGXS) with http service

Tags: angular, ngxs

Is there any other more clean way to return a value from an http service through an action (NGXS)? Or should we always update the "result" state just to be consulted on your return?

The code below works, is very close to the documentation.
However, it does not seem very clean to me.

```
export class DeleteAction {
  static readonly type = '[Test] Delete';
  constructor(public id: number) { }
}
```

```
@State<TestStateModel>({
  name: 'test',
  defaults: {
    result: null
  }
})
export class TestState {

  constructor(
    private testService: TestService) {
  }

  @Selector()
  static getResult(state: TestStateModel): NotificationResult {
    return state.result;
  }

  @Action(DeleteAction)
  public delete({ patchState }: StateContext<TestStateModel>, { id }: DeleteAction) {
    return this.testService
      .delete(id)
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        tap(result => {
          patchState({ result });
        })
      );
  }
```

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent {

    @Select(SubjectState.getResult) result$;

    private delete(id: number): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.store.dispatch(new DeleteAction(id))
      .pipe(withLatestFrom(this.result$))
      .subscribe(([_, r]) => {
        const result = r as NotificationResult;
        if (result.isValid) {
          // ...
        } else {
          // ...
        }
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }
}
```

```
export interface NotificationResult {
  isValid: boolean;
  messages: NotificationMessage[];
}
```

Since I will not use the "result" beyond calling the "Delete" method, it seems unnecessary to have to create a state just for this purpose.

Is there any other more elegant way?

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly, please? > `Is there any other more elegant way` of what? :) > `Is there any other more elegant way to return a value from an http service through an action` how can returning be "elegant"? Cheers:)

Comment: Hello, @Shadow
Thank's for your time.

Suppose I have 8 actions in my code and they all return a NotificationResult.
I would not like to store the state of the result to be able to read it.

I would just like to use the return of a direct Action on the component.

In this way it is written (my example), I always need to update the state to be able to read the information in the component.

Just to be able to read the result.
And in this example, the data would only be used once, it can be discarded.

Comment: @Shadow
I referred to clean code.

Comment: I'm confused about some parts and I'm explaining why. > `have 8 actions in my code and they all return a NotificationResult` actions do not return anything, actions are just commands. I'm not really knowledgable in your requirements and what you would want to achieve. First of all that `isLoading` property can also be stored in the state and updated there so you don't need to manipulate this property in your component. Also `store.dispatch` currently returns the whole state and it will be changed to `Observable<void>` in the 4.0.0 version.

Comment: @Shadow 
Yes, exactly.
The only way you can read an Action result is by accessing its state.
Just like my example.

So I mentioned if there was any other way to capture this "result" without having to go through the state.

If there is not, patience.
I understand that in this example I would not need to use state management. However, it seems strange to me to use 3 or 4 services by Action and one or the other is not.

I would like to keep all the rules in one place.

Comment: As for "IsLoading", yes, in this example it should be in state.
But imagine I have a page with 6 child components and they all have their "IsLoading" isolated.

I wonder if it would be better to keep IsLoading on each child component (out of state) or if I should write IsLoadingChildA, IsLoadingChildB, IsLoadingChildC.

As I am starting with NGXS, I am perhaps having some conceptual questions that I do not find in consistent examples.

Comment: The point is there is not such thing as "action result". NGXS is built upon the CQRS pattern where actions are commands and they do not return anything. I would not advise to do any calculations after dispatched action is handled in the `subscribe` block. You've got to dispatch an action but provide your `result$` stream to some component binding via `async` pipe. Inside that component you could have a setter decorated with `@Input` thus you can do any manipulations with `result.isValid` there. Child states are a way of layering but it's quite complex topic.

Comment: The question for me is: What do you want to do with the `isValid` return value? This seems to be something that can be handled in the action. If it is a message that should appear it can be handled by your state management, by dispatching another action. If it is updating a list, this should definitely be handled by your state management 
Referring to multiple loading states, with NGXS you can have substates for each component: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/sub-states

Comment: thank you very much for your attention, Shadow.

I understand. I already work with CQRS at the back end.

My intention was to reduce the excessive number of actions in the state (perhaps some that I consider unnecessary).

Comment: I will read more about substates.
Thanks for the clarification, @DanielHabenicht

Answer (score -1):

It would be cleaner to not chain looking at the delete result to the dispatch. Rather the current approach of having the delete method:

1. Dispatch the Delete action
2. Wait for the action to complete
3. Look at the latest value from the state
4. React to it

You could:

1. Have the delete method dispatch the delete action
2. Subscribe to changes to $result (e.g. in an init method) and react appropriately to the changes you get

That seems cleaner to me.  Thoughts?

Comment: thank's for your time, @RichDuncan.
I believe there is no right answer.

Today many things are much clearer to me.
I'm just trying to find the perfect code.

What you suggest is that I have an insertResult, updateResult, deleteResult, to get the init method to handle the last result of each action differently?

It is an alternative.